# UILocalNotification from previous install in ios9 (with CLLocationManager)

Tags: ios, objective-c, cllocationmanager, uilocalnotification

I have created a very simple app that use `CLLocationManager` with `CLBeaconRegion`.
When the application is in background and the user `enters/exits` a region, it creates a corresponding notification ("Welcome"/"Goodbye").

The project works fine, except I keep receiving old notifications from previous installation when the user `enters/exits` region.

"`monitoredRegions`" inside `CLLocationManager` only contains the current one.

local notifications are send through "`presentLocalNotificationNow`".

If you have any idea how I can receive only the notifications from the current installation..

Comment: are you using repeatInterval in  your notification ? and what mean current installation.

Comment: I don't use repeatInterval. By current installation, I meant the application I installed, and not the one I uninstall.. Does that make it clear?

Comment: you receiving the notification form that app which you remove ?

Comment: same app, 2 different installations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found why I do not receive the correct notification at the right time.
Once a region is added to the `UILocalNotification`, the notification is not send right after a call to `presentLocalNotificationNow`